# Django pagination is not working

Tags: python, django, pagination

following a tutorial I've done 2 times bfore and now pagination is not working
I get the following error

```
TypeError at /posts/
object of type 'method' has no len()
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/posts/
Django Version: 1.9.2
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
object of type 'method' has no len()
Exception Location: /Users/ray/Desktop/uply/my-server/lib/python3.5/site-    packages/django/core/paginator.py in _get_count, line 77
Python Executable:  /Users/ray/Desktop/uply/my-server/bin/python
Python Version: 3.5.1
Python Path:    
['/Users/ray/Desktop/uply/my-server/src',
'/Users/ray/Desktop/uply/my-server/lib/python35.zip',
'/Users/ray/Desktop/uply/my-server/lib/python3.5',
'/Users/ray/Desktop/uply/my-server/lib/python3.5/plat-darwin',
'/Users/ray/Desktop/uply/my-server/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload',
'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5',
'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/plat-darwin',
'/Users/ray/Desktop/uply/my-server/lib/python3.5/site-packages']
Server time:    Wed, 10 Feb 2016 23:25:54 -0500
```

this is my code in my views.py

```
def post_list(request):
  queryset_list = Post.objects.all
  paginator = Paginator(queryset_list, 25)

  page = request.GET.get('page')
  try:
    queryset = paginator.page(page)
  except PageNotAnInteger:
    queryset = paginator.page(1)
  except EmptyPage:
    queryset = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

  template = "posts/post_list.html"
  name = "user"
  context = {
    "object_list": queryset,
    "name": name
  }
  return render(request, template, context)
```

I have done this and variations of this tutorial all in the last two months using the same latest version of django and pyhthon. What is going on? How could this be the problem
     object of type 'method' has no len()

when I've done this before? all help is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`all` is a method:

```
queryset_list = Post.objects.all()
```

Comment: Thanks @nima. fixed it. That was it

Answer (score 0):

Change **Post.objects.all** to **Post.objects.all()**

```
def post_list(request):
  queryset_list = Post.objects.all()
  paginator = Paginator(queryset_list, 25)

  page = request.GET.get('page')
  try:
    queryset = paginator.page(page)
  except PageNotAnInteger:
    queryset = paginator.page(1)
  except EmptyPage:
    queryset = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

  template = "posts/post_list.html"
  name = "user"
  context = {
    "object_list": queryset,
    "name": name
  }
  return render(request, template, context)
```